# Android how to use Toolbar in ListActivity?

Tags: android, toolbar, listactivity

I made a ListActivity:

```
 public class NoteListActivity extends ListActivity{
 }
```

and the following methods are no longer available:

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But I can use:

```
    setActionBar(toolbar);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Note that I used Support library in other activities in the same project. It means I have the correct gradle dependency added.

How do I use ListActivity and android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that in `ListActivity`.

If you want to access `getSupportActionBar()`, you need to extend your class with `AppCompatActivity`.

**My Suggestion :** Don't use ListActivty as you want to use `ToolBar`. Create an `Activity` and then only have `ListView` within that `Activity`. It'll work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AppCompatCallback callback = new AppCompatCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode actionMode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode actionMode) {
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    AppCompatDelegate delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, callback);

    delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    delegate.setContentView(R.layout.saved_report_activity);

    Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    delegate.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    delegate.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(SavedReportActivity.this);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) is the direct child class of *FragmentActivity* of support v4 .Read this article

> http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html
>   so for your requirement, `public class NoteListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {...}`

Just change your dependency,Like :

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding a support library toolbar style and then adding the style to my list activity in the manifest.

In styles.xml:

```
     <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
```

In Manifest

```
    <activity android:theme="@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle"
              android:name="@string/my_activity_name"
              android:label="@string/my_activity_label"/>
```

This should add a toolbar to your activity that you can add items to and process events with, etc...

Comment: Yes, actionBar is deprecated and you should not use ListActivity but for smooth migration of legacy application. This code works